# How to include a full mat-menu in a parent menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material

We want to split a large menu (e.g. like the `Nested menu` example from the [material components docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples)) into separate smaller components.

E.g. in this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me42ci?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffish-menu.component.ts) we moved the fish menu to a separate component: [fish-menu.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me42ci?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffish-menu.component.ts):

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "fish-menu",
  template: `
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="fish">Fishes</button>

    <mat-menu #fish="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Baikal oilfish</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Bala shark</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Ballan wrasse</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Bamboo shark</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Banded killifish</button>
    </mat-menu>
  `
})
export class FishMenuComponent {}
```

And include it in the [parent menu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me42ci?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-nested-example.html), like so:

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="animals">Animal index</button>

<mat-menu #animals="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="vertebrates">Vertebrates</button>
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="invertebrates">Invertebrates</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #vertebrates="matMenu">
  <!-- our child-component does not work as expected -->
  <fish-menu></fish-menu>
  <!-- other children are okay -->
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="amphibians">Amphibians</button>
  <!-- etc. -->
```

But the included menu does not work as expected, when we hoover the menu item:

1. the fish menu is not opened (unless we click it)
2. the other menus are not closed (when the fish menu is opened)

**NOTE**
We want to include the full menu in the child component: i.e. the button with `matMenuTriggerFor` and the related `mat-menu` (because the very same menu should be included in multiple places in the production app). And the parent menu is not always the same: i.e. we have many different parent-menus which are composed of different sub-menus.

How can we make this work as expected?

Comment: Not an answer but consider this as an option: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-menus

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue as well and this is caused by your child component not having the same context for `matMenu` as your parent. To work around this I passed an object of my child menus to my parent through an input and built them dynamically.

If you are planning to have a single component that displays your `matMenuTriggerFor` button I believe your solution should be much more straightforward. You can house your entire menu in a single component and use it in multiple other components.

I've done something like what you described here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me42ci-bbbnfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-nested-example.html

---

EDIT

I came up with something that might work for you. You could pass in your top level menu items through ng-content:

```
<app-menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Aliens</button>
</app-menu>
```

menu.component.ts:

```
  <mat-menu #animals="matMenu">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="vertebrates">
      Vertebrates
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="invertebrates">
      Invertebrates
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me42ci-bbbnfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-nested-example.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your Stackblitz example is not what we need: in your example, the menu is always exactly the same. But we always have different parent menus which are composed of sub-menus that need to be reused.

Comment: Building the menus dynamically in code could be a last resort - but would be a lot of work, because we have many menus that need different features.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding that aspect of your requirements. A possible path forward for you could a single component to share all you sub menus that has an input for the top level configuration. When you say top-level, do you mean what is at the Vertebrates / Invertebrates level of your example?